# Symfony translate database value before output

Tags: symfony1, localization, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I have a table for 'alerts'. I would like to store there the alerts for the users in Engligh, and translate the alert into the users' culture before showing it. Like an usual message which is translated with the `__()` function.

Is this thing possible in Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many alerts do you have? Doubt that more than 100, no? It is normal to store stuff this size in xml translation files, anyway they are cached. And it is more simple to add new items in xml files than in database.

Comment: Another method I've been thinking to is to store the alert codes and with an function to output the translated message. Would this be better?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using i18n models, which store same values but in different languages.
http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/13-I18n-and-L10n
This works in symfony 1.4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Should be no problem if you have messages.en.xml and messages.xx.xml which reflect the entries in the db. I haven't done it but I don't see why it should work ...